# jQuery call not being triggered

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code that reveals different text when being hovered over but cant seem to get it to work.

```
$('a.spoiler').hover(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var content = $(this).attr("content");
  $(this).text(content).attr("content", text)
});
```

Which is in the HTML Page Head.

and the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script>    
      //Spoiler hiding
      $('a.spoiler').hover(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        var content = $(this).attr("content");
        $(this).text(content).attr("content", text)
      });
    </script>       
  </head>   
  <body>
    <a href="" onclick="return false" class="spoiler" content="Winner">
      Reveal
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I cant seem to get it to work.

Any Ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to attach the event before element is loaded on page. make sure that element is loaded using document ready/load function and then attach the event:

```
 $(function(){
   $('a.spoiler').hover(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        var content = $(this).attr("content");
        $(this).text(content).attr("content", text)
    });
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v6ewqt21/)**

Comment: Hmmm,  what happens if the element isn't loaded onto the page until later.  For example, what if the element was only loaded after an Ajax call was made?

Comment: is it better practice to put custom JS at the bottom of the body element rather than the head, and only keep library/framework references in the head, to make the page load faster?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @karthikr's answer: The way your code currently is you are attaching a listener to an element that does not exist the moment this code is interpreted.

Wrapping your code into

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // your code
}
```

Will make sure the html is interpreted before your script is executed, thus making sure the element you want to attach the handler to does exist.